# How to configure create-react-app server to not redirect requests or URL stems?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I've used [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) to create a new application and have then run...

```
npm run eject
```

...in order to get full control over the application.

What I want to do is update the server so that I can use my own Express middleware configuration to set up [Passport.js](http://passportjs.org/) and Express Routing to authenticate against another repository (and Alfresco repository in this case) and then proxy all subsequent XHR requests through a function that attaches the session token.

The issue I'm having is that each XHR request automatically gets redirected back to "/index.html" (including any attempt to login).

I'm sure that there must be something relatively straight-forward to configure in the webpack dev server configuration but as I'm not sure what!

Comment: This is just my opinion, but I think you should make the server a separate node application. Let `create-react-app` do strictly front-end work.

Comment: Yes, I'm starting to come to that conclusion as well... I can configure a proxy  as described in the instructions